# Multiprocess is less efficient

Tags: elixir

I currently learning Elixir through the website exercism.io.
I had the problem "Sum Of Multiples" which is:

> If we list all the natural numbers up to but not including 20 that are
>   multiples of either 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9, 10, 12, 15, and 18.
>   The sum of these multiples is 78

I solved this problem with this code:

```
defmodule SumOfMultiples do
  @doc """
  Adds up all numbers from 1 to a given end number that are multiples of the factors provided.
  """
  @spec to(non_neg_integer, [non_neg_integer]) :: non_neg_integer
  def to(limit, factors) do
    1..limit - 1
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn(x,acc) ->
      is_multiple? = factors
      |> Enum.map(&(rem(x,&1) === 0))
      |> Enum.any?
      if is_multiple?, do: [x|acc], else: acc
    end)
    |> Enum.sum
  end
end
```

But I recently discover Processes in Elixir so I wanted to solve the problem with multiprocesses:

```
defmodule SumOfMultiples do
  @doc """
  Adds up all numbers from 1 to a given end number that are multiples of the factors provided.
  """
  @spec to(non_neg_integer, [non_neg_integer]) :: non_neg_integer
  def to(limit, factors) do
    me = self
    1..limit - 1
    |> Enum.map(fn(x) ->
      spawn(SumOfMultiples, :is_multiple?, [x, factors, me])
    end)
    |> Enum.map(fn(_) ->
      receive do
        {true, n} -> n
        {false, n} -> 0
      end
    end)
    |> Enum.sum
  end

  def is_multiple?(n, factors, pid) do

    flag = factors
    |> Enum.map(&(rem(n,&1) === 0))
    |> Enum.any?
    send pid, {flag, n}
  end
end
```

I use parallel map to solve that. Is works but the thing is it is 4x less performant than the single-process version.

It will be very useful if someone could explain me why there is such a difference of performance because I have planned to resolve the rest of the exercism.io problem with a multiprocesses version.

Thank you !

--------------------- update ---------------------

Thank you for your answer ! it turn out you were right ! thanks for explaning ! here is my new implementation:

```
defmodule SumOfMultiples do
  @doc """
  Adds up all numbers from 1 to a given end number that are multiples of the factors provided.
  """
  @spec to(non_neg_integer, [non_neg_integer]) :: non_neg_integer
  def to(limit, factors) do
    me = self
    1..limit - 1
    |> Stream.chunk(200, 200, Stream.cycle([0]))
    |> Enum.map(fn(x) ->
      spawn(SumOfMultiples, :do_to, [x, factors, me])
    end)
    |> Enum.map(fn(_) ->
      receive do
        n -> n
      end
    end)
    |> Enum.sum
  end

  def do_to(list, factors, pid) do
    result = list
      |> Enum.reduce([], fn(x,acc) ->
      is_multiple? = factors
      |> Enum.map(&(rem(x,&1) === 0))
      |> Enum.any?
      if is_multiple?, do: [x|acc], else: acc
    end)
    |> Enum.sum
    send pid, result
  end

end
```

The maximum seems to be at 200. Now I'm ~40% faster than the single process ! YAY !

Comment: Stream.chunk_by() is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you split the work too thin. The overhead of starting a new process was bigger than the gain of doing this in parallel. A single run of a process (until it will be rescheduled by the VM) is given 2000 reductions, which more-or-less correspond to 2000 function calls. To see a real benefit of parallelization, you should try to split the work in chunks of that size to gain the biggest benefit from parallelizing the work.

Comment: I thought the limit was 2K reductions.